# Getting uninitialized constant error in rails app, but can pull data fine from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm trying to use the twitter gem, in my home#controller I have

```
@tweets = Twitter.user_timeline("pantsstore").limit(2)
```

and

```
<%= @tweets %> in homeController#index
```

but I'm getting an

```
uninitialized constant Spree::HomeController::Twitter
```

error. Where should I put 'require 'twitter''? Or how do I initialize the variable Twitter? I can pull tweets fine from the rails console with

```
Twitter.user_timeline("pantsstore").limit(2)
```

Comment: You should put the require at the top of the file.

Comment: When I do that I get this error: cannot load such file -- twitter. Thanks for your response. It just doesn't make sense to me why its working from the rails console and not in the app.

Comment: Where's the library? What's the name of the library? How do you have your library auto-includes set up?

Comment: I have no idea. Where should it be? I just added the gem to the gemfile and ran bundler.